# SQL: division not returning accurate results even after trying cast

Tags: sql, division

Thanks in advance for any help. Basically I'm not getting decimal results:
Here is my code:

```
select 
practitioner_id, 
count([Number of Acorns Used]) as [Surveys Used], 
count(patid) as [Number of Clients], 
cast(count(cast ([Number of Acorns Used] as float))/
count(cast (patid as float)) as decimal(10,2)) as [Survey Use Rate]
from #Results
group by practitioner_id
order by count([Number of Acorns Used]) desc
```

Here are some partial results (practitioner_id is removed):

```
removed 6   46  0.00
removed 5   11  0.00
removed 5   20  0.00
removed 4   26  0.00
removed 4   28  0.00
removed 4   6   0.00
removed 4   32  0.00
removed 2   2   1.00
removed 1   1   1.00
```

![data results]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZrgI.png

Comment: You've tried using data type float?

Comment: When you added the SQL tag, a pretty large red box appeared that suggested you also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, because features and syntax between them varies. Is there a reason you chose to ignore that suggestion? It's there for a reason - it not only gets you answers more quickly, but it avoids wasting the time of people who write answers for one DBMS only to find out it won't work for you because you're using something else.

Comment: Also, if you can, dump some example data into SQLFiddle or something and show us what you expect the results to be.

Comment: Are you certain you want to count() the [Number of acorns used] column? The name of the attribute suggests it's already a count, and I wonder if you want to sum() the number of acorns used.

Comment: Thanks Ken for the advice on the specific DBMS. It's SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Hi Bryan. Thanks for really thinking about the code. Sometimes clinicians use the survey multiple times during a visit (and a number greater than one is stored in this field). I want to exclude that scenario. So I really do want to count only once each time.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're not getting decimal results is that the output of count() is an int, so you want to move the cast to outside the count() function.

```
select 
practitioner_id, 
count([Number of Acorns Used]) as [Surveys Used], 
count(patid) as [Number of Clients], 
 cast(count([Number of Acorns Used]) as decimal(10,2))/
 cast(count(patid) as decimal(10,2))
  as [Survey Use Rate]
from #Results
group by practitioner_id
order by count([Number of Acorns Used]) desc
```

Comment: Excellent point. When working with SQL, any flavor, it's always important to know what type of numbers you're working with, and the limitations and "quirks" of those types of numbers. Sometimes 1 / 1.x will give you 1 instead of 0.y.

Answer (score 0):

Float is not an exact numeric datatype. So it will sometimes give you slightly off results. Use `decimal(7,2)` instead. Or whatever you need to fit your numbers. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/numeric-types

Comment: Citing the SQL Server documentation is only relevant if the poster has indicated they are using SQL Server.

Comment: True. I jumped the gun on that one. However, that link does give some fairly generic info about numeric datatypes that will apply to several main languages.

Comment: are there any RDBMS that use [ ] around the attribute names other than ms sql server?

Comment: MS Access :) and SQLite, to be compatible with these.

Comment: by the way, floating binary point can give rounding errors on decimals because of what it is, not because of the DBMS. is there any system where a type named float means floating decimal point and not the floating binary point?

Comment: MS Access is still t-sql, but whoa SQLite - so polite of them to ... be compatible with ... ms sql.

Answer (score 0):

You've got your cast in the wrong place. For example, the result of this is an integer:

`count(cast ([Number of Acorns Used] as float))`.

Change it to `cast(count([Number of Acorns Used]) as DECIMAL(19,6)`.

You could ascertain this by just selecting the column on its own.

I also suggest using decimal not float (which is imprecise and has very limited practical use)

So try this for the full expression:

```
cast(count([Number of Acorns Used]) as DECIMAL(19,6))
/
cast(count(patid) as decimal(10,2)) as [Survey Use Rate]
```

The thing is.... I wouldn't expect those counts to return different numbers unless you used `DISTINCT`. But I don't know what type of SQL this is.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental issue is that your database (presumably SQL Server) does integer division.  So, when you divide two integers, the result is an integer.  You can then cast it to whatever you like, but the process is:  3/2 --> 1 --> 1.00.

I usually just multiple a value by 1.0 to do the division:

```
select practitioner_id, 
       count([Number of Acorns Used]) as [Surveys Used], 
       count(patid) as [Number of Clients], 
       (count([Number of Acorns Used]) * 1.0 /
        count(patid)
       ) as [Survey Use Rate]
from #Results r
group by practitioner_id
order by [Surveys Used] desc;
```

As others have noted, counting a float is the same as counting an integer, or counting a string, or counting a date.  The `count()` always returns an integer.